# @RolesAllowed failing after upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, okta

I am attempting to upgrade one of my applications from Spring Boot 3.0.2 to Spring Boot 3.0.6 to deal with a [CVE](https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-20873).

I currently use method level security in my application just fine.

```
@GetMapping(value = "ping",produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
@RolesAllowed(Constants.PUBLIC_CLOUD_ADMIN_ROLE)
public ResponseEntity<String> ping(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt principal) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok("We made it!");
}
```

Due to how my security provider is configured by my infosec department I have to override the value prepended to my roles like so.

```
@Bean
GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
    return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("");
}
```

However after upgrading to 3.0.6 the same requests starts returning a 400 bad request with this as the error message.

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2023-05-08 04:52:22",
  "status" : "BAD_REQUEST",
  "message" : "thunder_admin_app3536576 should not start with  since  is automatically prepended when using hasAnyRole. Consider using hasAnyAuthority instead."
}
```

The blank between with and since in the error message leads me to believe it doesn't like how I am setting the prefix to blank, but that is purely a guess.

I have attempted upgrading my okta spring boot starter as well to make sure those are on compatible versions, but the issue persists.

I looked through the release notes for that version of Spring Security and didn't see anything related to this, but it's beyond possible that I missed something obvious.

Comment: I don't think anything has changed in this regard in the Springboot 3.0.6 upgrade.

Comment: All I can be sure of is when I change the version to 3.0.6 without changing anything else it breaks. I didn't see anything in the change log that would suggest this behavior, but I can reproduce it every time.

Comment: For reasons that are still unclear to me the problem goes away in 3.1.0 but persists in 3.0.7.

I am choosing to just fail forward.